Order by computed column in graphql supabase
Is it possible to order by a computed column with graphql ? Assuming to this discussion, it is possible with supabase client API call : https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/7875
But I would like do the same from graphql.
My table with computed column items_count :
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."group" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" "text" NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."items" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" "text" NOT NULL,
  "group_id" SERIAL REFERENCES "public"."group"("id")
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."items_count"("group" public."group")
  RETURNS INT
  STRICT
  VOLATILE
  LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM items
WHERE group_id = "group".id;
$$;

The generated graphql schema returns group :
type group implements Node {
  id: Int!
  itemsCollection(...): itemsConnection
  items_count: Int
  name: String!
  nodeId: ID!
}

This query is valid and returns correct result with items_count field :
query AllGroups($sort: [groupOrderBy!]) {
  groupCollection(orderBy: $sort) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        items_count
      }
    }
  }
}

But it is not possible to sort by items_count. Indeed the generated graphql schema returns groupOrderBy :
input groupOrderBy {
  id: OrderByDirection
  name: OrderByDirection
}

